# Make SQL function run for every value in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, missing-data

This may be a novice question, but I cannot for the life of me figure this out.

Before I explain my stored procedure I will describe my tables and show examples. There is the `TicketBook` table that houses all TicketBooks that have been issued to a unit. TicketBooks are 25 Tickets long.

eg:

```
                        TicketBooks
                        -----------
TicketBookNum  |  TicketNum  |  UnitID  |  FirstTicket  |  LastTicket | Used
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
     101              101          120           101           126       Yes
     101              102          120           101           126       Yes
     101              103          120           101           126       No
     101              104          120           101           126       Yes
     etc...
```

This table has all tickets that are used and not used in the database.

**Different TicketBooks can be issued to different units at the same time. So TicketBook 101 can be issued to Unit 120, while TicketBook 151 can be issued to 140.**

What my stored procedure needs to do is return all Tickets that are marked as not used, but also have a ticket that is greater than it that is marked Used.

Example:

```
TicketBookNum  |  TicketNum | Used
----------------------------------
   101              101        Yes
   101              102        Yes
   101              103        No
   101              104        Yes
   101              105        Yes
   101              106        No
   101              107        No
   etc..
```

So the stored procedure returns Ticket `103`, but not `106` and `107` because there are no tickets inside that ticketbook after them that are marked as Used.

This is currently the stored procedure that I am using:

```
select TicketNum
from TicketBooks
where Used='No'
and TicketNum between 92226 and 92251
and TicketNum < (select top 1 TicketNum
                from TicketBooks
                where Used='Yes'
                and TicketNum between 92226 and 92251
                order by TicketNum desc)
order by TicketNum desc
```

This will return the missing tickets from the TicketBook 82226. If I try to change the parameters on the `between` clause then it does not return the correct results. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just a comment that doesn't address your problem: you should just use `max()` instead of `top 1` and `order by`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I understand what you are trying to do.  I think the thing you are missing is that your subquery does not map to the ticket book from your outer query.  So you want something like this:

```
select TicketNum
from TicketBooks a
where Used='No'
and TicketNum < (select MAX(b.TicketNum)
            from TicketBooks b
            where b.Used='Yes'
            and b.TicketBookNum = a.TicketBookNum)
order by TicketNum desc
```

Comment: This worked out perfectly, and it makes sense what you are doing. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2):

You could use a common table expression to wrap the range limit in and do a exists query like this:

```
;with cte as (
    select * from TicketBooks where TicketNum between 101 and 126
    )

select * from cte where Used = 'no'
and exists (
    select 1 
    from cte t
    where t.TicketNum > cte.ticketnum
    and t.used='yes'
    )
```

This is still restricted to a hard coded range; a better option might be to build the range from the FirstTicket/LastTicket values in the source table.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 ;WITH cte AS
(
 select TicketNum,ROW_NUMBER() OVER
    (PARTITION BY TicketBookNum,Used ORDER BY TicketNum) rn
from TicketBooks

)
SELECT * FROM cte 
where Used='No' AND rn =1
```

Example

```
CREATE TABLE #t (ticket INT ,ticketno INT, fla VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO #t VALUES(1,1,'yes'),
(1,2,'yes'),
(1,4,'No'),
(1,5,'No')

;WITH cte AS
(

SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ticket,fla ORDER BY ticketno) rn FROM #t 
 )

 SELECT * FROM cte WHERE fla ='no'AND rn =1
```

Comment: I gave this a try. It doesn't work with the `where Used='No'`, but if I take it out I get the first unused ticket from each ticketbook. This is almost what I want. I am looking for every unused ticket in that ticketbook that is before the last used one.

Answer (score 1):

```
select TicketNum
from TicketBooks as t
where Used='No'
    and TicketNum between 92226 and 92251
    and exists (
        select 1
        from TicketBooks as t2
        where t2.Used='Yes'
            /* not sure if you actually want to restrict the range here */
            and t2.TicketNum between 92226 and 92251
            and t2.TicketNum > t.TicketNum
    )
order by TicketNum desc
```

I couldn't make sense of whether you wanted to search within ticketbooks or explicit ranges or what. But I wrote this to show you the `EXISTS` option. You also might find `< ANY (...)` and `< ALL (...)` to be useful in the future. Many people overlook those.